# Need help manipulating URL using concatenation to span 2 years of archived data in R

Tags: r, url, web-scraping, web-crawler, concatenation

I would like to concatenate the following values in R.

```
day <- sprintf("%02d", 1:31)
month <- sprintf("%02d", 1:12)
year <- 2015:as.numeric(format(Sys.time(), "%Y"))
```

I need them to be in the following format `2015/01/01012015 (YYYY/MM/MMDDYYYY)` where MMs would have to be equal at all times.
 Ultimately I want to attach it to the end on this URL `http://brocktonpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/` so I can pass it as an argument to a download function to download the files.

Here is what I have so far

```
links <- NULL
i <- 1
while (i <= length(year)) {

links[i] <- paste0("http://brocktonpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/",year[i],     sep = "/")
i = i + 1
}
```

I would like it to span the entire year of 2015 and 2016. 
For example:

```
http://brocktonpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/01012015.pdf  
http://brocktonpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/01022015.pdf  
http://brocktonpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/01032015.pdf  
http://brocktonpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/01042015.pdf  
...  
http://brocktonpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/02012015.pdf  
http://brocktonpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/02022015.pdf   
http://brocktonpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/02032015.pdf 
...    
etc
```

Comment: You can also look at `seq.Date` in `base`. Not all months have the same number of days (and some vary every four years...). Then you can output these dates as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `seq.Date`. It's much easier.

```
prefix <- "http://brocktonpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/"
AllDays <- seq.Date(from = as.Date('2015-01-01'), to = Sys.Date(), by = "day")
links <- paste0(prefix, format(AllDays, '%Y/%m/%m%d%Y'), '.pdf')
print(links)
```

Comment: Notice there are no loops here. Vectorized operations can be hard to get your head around initially, but your code become much simpler when you use them.

Comment: Thank you! This is way better than what I was trying to do. I knew about seq(), but not about seq.date(). Thanks again

Comment: I noticed that some links for the actual webpage end like this:   http://brocktonpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/1516.pdf. The last digits for month and day don't have leading zero. Is there a way to create the same links without the leading zero when the  digits are less than zero?

Comment: This is what I did  
`gsub(" 0", " ", format(as.Date("2015-09-02"), "%Y, %m, %d"))`